# To Parse A Json Array

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, object

I'm trying to parse a json array, where a partcular node, under some conditions comes as a array and sometimes as object.

Example:

```
{
    "children":
    { 
      "id":"3",
              "subject":"dddd",
              "details":"dddd",
              "beginDate":"2012-03-08T00:00:00+01:00",
              "endDate":"2012-03-18T00:00:00+01:00",
              "campus":
                       { 
                         "id":"2",
                         "name":"paris"
                       }
           }
}
```

and sometimes as:

```
{"children":
        [{
          "id":"1",
          "subject":"android",
          "details":"test",
          "beginDate":"2012-03-26T00:00:00+02:00",
          "endDate":"2012-04-09T00:00:00+02:00",
          "campus":{
                    "id":"1",
                    "name":"lille"
                   }
        },

{
 "id":"2",
         "subject":"lozlzozlo",
         "details":"xxx",
         "beginDate":"2012-03-14T00:00:00+01:00",
         "endDate":"2012-03-18T00:00:00+01:00",
         "campus":{
                   "id":"1",
                   "name":"lille"
                  }
        }]
}
```

I have tried using this,

```
if (jobj123 instanceof JSONArray) {
     // It's an array
     Log.i("It's an array", "It's an array");

    } else if (jobj123 instanceof JSONObject) {
     // It's an object
     Log.i("It's an object", "It's an object");
    }
```

But the 'if' condition always fails and else loop is executed, Can anyone help me solving this issue.

Comment: it means the node 'children' sometimes comes as Object and sometimes as Children. Help me parsing this Json response

Comment: *a partcular node, under some conditions comes as a array and sometimes as object.* that's some bad design there

Comment: As far as i can understand, if there is only one 'child' object, the "children" is become json object, otherwise it becomes json array. Just return json array no matter how many children it returns (if you have control over the server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 JSONObject children_sub_category_object = children
       .getJSONObject(j).optJSONObject("children");
     if (children_sub_category_object != null) {

      children_sub_jsonobject = children.getJSONObject(j)
        .getJSONObject("children");

      Log.e("Object", "Object");

     } else {
      children_sub_category = children.getJSONObject(j)
        .getJSONArray("children");

      Log.e("Array", "Array");
     }
```

Try that out. That worked for me well. Let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve and check the type of the the "children" object.

Try this:

```
if (jobj123.has("children") && jobj123.get("children") instanceof JSONObject) {
  // it is a JSONObject
  JSONObject children = jobj123.getJSONObject("children");

  // handle your children ...

}
else if (jobj123.has("children") && jobj123.get("children") instanceof JSONArray) {
  // it is an JSONArray
  JSONArray childrenArray = jobj123.getJSONArray("children");

  // loop children
  for (int i = 0; i < childrenArray.length(); i++)
  {
    if (childrenArray.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
      JSONObject children = childrenArray.getJSONObject(i);

      // handle your children ...

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your String into this function which uses nested try catch. it works:

```
void parse(String s){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try{
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("children");
        for(int i = 0;i <jArray.length();i++){
            Log.i("array type", jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        try{
            JSONObject innerObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("children");
            Log.i("object type",innerObj.getString("id"));
        }catch(Exception exx){
            exx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```